# Use Multiple sql addition,selection in same php file and return appropriate result

Tags: php, sql, database

I am adding some type of long text(MSG1) in my database using KID number of individual User,spelt as K-ID which is uniquely generated and alloted to user while registration & entered in database. I have messages.php file which contains some validation which is working fine.I have more than 3 selections  & addition to database in same table. It is not selecting the field nor inserting  a new row entry. I have written code like following .I want to Select MSG1 WHERE KID is equal to KID. & add new EMAIL,FNAME,LNAME,KID for registration to database  & MSG1,2,3,4 will be added afterwards.

My Table `CHAT`:-

```
EMAIL
FNAME
LNAME
KID
MSG1
MSG2
MSG3
MSG4
```

My messages.php file:

```
mysql_connect("host","user","password","database"); 
$query="SELECT FNAME,LNAME,KID FROM `CHAT` WHERE KID='$KIDA'";
mysql_real_escape_string($KIDA);     
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{ 
  $rows[1]=$row;
}
if($query)  
 if(!(empty($rows[1][MSG1]))) 
 { 
   echo     'Message From ';
   echo "<a><b>";
   echo $rows[1][FNAME]; echo " ";
   echo $rows[1][LNAME];
   echo "</  a></b>"; 
   echo   "<b>Message Recieved from  KID Number:- </b>"; 
   echo $rows[1][KID];


}
 mysql_connect("host","user","password","database"); 

 $SAS="SELECT MSG1 FROM `CHAT` WHERE KID='$KID'";
 mysql_real_escape_string($KID); 
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($SAS))
 { 
   $rows[1]=$row;
 }
if($SAS) 
{
  echo"<br><b>";
  echo  $rows[1][MSG1]; 
  echo "</ b><br>"; 
  echo "<b>Your KID Number is</b> ".'$KID';   
} 
else 
{ 
  die('No messages');
}
?>
```

Here $KID is the 1st user's logged in KID Number & $KIDA is the 2nd users KID number which the 2nd user has sended a msg with his KID number to User 1st.
My final errors:-
1) I'm getting php error :- mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied
argument is not a valid MySQL result
resource.
2) No addition or Selection from database.
3) I have multiple operations from database, how to make it more easy/simple

Your Suggestions Would help me, To learn something new. Thanks for Your Help.

Comment: You're not actually querying the database anywhere. You need to run your query through `mysql_query()` first. Or better yet, switch to mysqli_ or PDO, as they both make it easier to write more secure code.

Comment: You're also not using `mysql_real_escape_string()` correctly. You have to assign the result to a variable, and then use this in the query in place of the original variable.

Comment: @andrewsi ,i know mysql_query is not implemented in above code but even using it, ,it's not working thats also one of my problem.

Comment: Can you explain me it in code?  Please would be greatfull.

Comment: @VikrantKelkar - What happens when you add in `mysql_query`? Do you get an error? A white screen? The wrong data? Some of the right data?

Comment: Using mysql_query does not perform any of the selection, addition from database because, no value is returned in php file..but in my other php files its working perfectly but in this file somethings going wrong.

Comment: @VikrantKelkar - could you edit your question so we can see what you're trying?

Comment: In above code its straight showing No messages, even when `rows[1][MSG1]` exists In database

Comment: @VikrantKelkar - but you're not actually querying the database in the code above. Of course it's not going to find any records. You need to run your SQL through `mysql_query` to get a result set, and then run through that to find the records.

Comment: Ok, can you please write down a sample code?  I would figure out my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will help you

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("host","user","password");
mysql_select_db("database",$connect);

$query="SELECT FNAME, LNAME, KID FROM CHAT WHERE KID='$KIDA'";
$result = mysql_query($query);     
if($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    echo     'Message From ';
    echo "<a><b>";
    echo $row["FNAME"]; echo " ";
    echo $row["LNAME"];
    echo "</  a></b>"; 
    echo   "<b>Message Recieved from  KID Number:- </b>"; 
    echo $row["KID"];
}

$SAS="SELECT MSG1 FROM `CHAT` WHERE KID='$KID'";
$result = mysql_query($SAS); 
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($numRows>0) {
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
   { 
      echo"<br><b>";
      echo  $row["MSG1"]; 
      echo "</ b><br>"; 
      echo "<b>Your KID Number is</b> ".'$KID'; 
   }
} else {
  echo "no message"; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
// Firstly, sanitise the input.
// This is a lot easier in PDO or mysqli_*
$KID = mysql_real_escape_string($KID); 

$SAS="SELECT MSG1 FROM `CHAT` WHERE KID='$KID'";

// run the query, or generate an error message
$rowset = mysql_query($SAS) or die(mysql_error());

// Check to see if there's an entry in the database
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowset)) {
    echo"<br><b>";
    echo  $row['MSG1']; 
    echo "</b><br>"; 
    echo "<b>Your KID Number is</b> ".'$KID';   
} else { 
    die('No messages');
}
```

Comment: Can `if(mysql_num_rows()>0)` also be used to return $rows[1][MSG1] value. or give error ,or your method is more appropriate ?

Comment: In this case, `mysql_num_rows($rowset)` will tell you how many rows there are in the recordset. It won't return the data by itself.

Comment: Instead of the `if`, you can also use `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowset)) {`, which will cycle through all the results.